# How to know if a thread was waked up or time sliced (Producer-Consumer)

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm learning multi-thread in java and I've faced with a behavior that I can't understand why.

Before, some explanations: the producer needs to produce until the list is full. When producing, nothing stops consumer from consuming. Consumer consumes until the list is empty. The producer only starts to produce when the list has <10 elements.

Here is my code:

Producer class

```
class Producer extends Thread {
    private MyList list;
    public Producer(MyList list) {
       this.list = list;
    }

    public void run() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        try {
           list.put();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
           System.out.println("I WAS INTERRUPTED");
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Consumer

```
class Consumer extends Thread {

    private MyList list;
    public Consumer(MyList list) {
       this.list = list;    
    }
    public void run() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        try {
           list.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
           System.out.println("I WAS INTERRUPTED 2");
        }
    }
    }
}
```

List that has the shared resources

```
    public class MyList {

        private String[] dates = new String[100];
        private int index = -1;

        public int getIndex() {
           return index;
        }

        public synchronized void put() throws InterruptedException {

        if ((getIndex() + 1) == 100) {     
            System.out.println("List is full");
            wait();
        }


    /**
     * Here I need to know if this thread was woke up by the consumer, or it was 'restaured' due time-slice
     * 
     */

        if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && getIndex() >= 10) {
            System.out.println("List doesn't have the minimun quantity to start a production");
            wait();
        }

        dates[++index] = new Date().toString();
        System.out.println("put " + dates[index] + " at " + index);
        notifyAll();
        }

        public synchronized void get() throws InterruptedException {

        if (getIndex() < 0)
            wait();

        System.out.println("got " + dates[index--] + " at " + (index + 1));

      /**
     * Basically, to this example work I would need to put, if (getIndex() < 10) notifyAll() here,
     *  but that is a behavior for the producer and should not be in the consumer
     * 
     */
         notifyAll();

        }
    }
```

Then

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    MyList list = new MyList();

    Thread producer = new Producer(list);
    Thread consumer = new Consumer(list);

    producer.start();
    consumer.start();
    }
}
```

Sorry for that bunch of code, but it's not complicated code :)

Ok, go to the doubt, why those `I WAS INTERRUPTED` are never called?

and why (probably related with above) that `List doesn't have the minimun quantity to start a production` is also never called?

An actual output:

```
....
....
put Thu Oct 01 02:15:12 BRT 2015 at 93
put Thu Oct 01 02:15:12 BRT 2015 at 94
put Thu Oct 01 02:15:12 BRT 2015 at 95
put Thu Oct 01 02:15:12 BRT 2015 at 96
put Thu Oct 01 02:15:12 BRT 2015 at 97
put Thu Oct 01 02:15:12 BRT 2015 at 98
put Thu Oct 01 02:15:12 BRT 2015 at 99
List is full
got Thu Oct 01 02:15:12 BRT 2015 at 99
put Thu Oct 01 02:15:12 BRT 2015 at 99 <- this wouldn't happen
List is full
got Thu Oct 01 02:15:12 BRT 2015 at 99
put Thu Oct 01 02:15:12 BRT 2015 at 99 <- this wouldn't happen
List is full
...
...
```

**EDIT**

I've confused the things, I never call interrupt on my code, but this is not my purpose.

I want to know when the thread was 'woke up' by another thread and not from jvm due to the time-slice

Comment: The variables names do not match in `main` correct that

Comment: It's not getting called because you don't interrupt any thread anywhere in your code. You need to call `Thread.interrupt()` to interrupt a thread.

Comment: Check variable names for productor, consumidor. Should it be 'producer' and 'consumer'?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt then `notifyAll()` doesn't help in this case?

Comment: @JohnnyWiller Please read the Javadoc for [Object.wait()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait()). You need to - always - call `wait` from within a loop that checks the wait condition. Not sure if that fixed whatever your problem is, but this a part of the basics of using wait/notify - if that isn't correct, you can get all kinds of unexpected results.

Comment: Whether your thread was awoken or time-sliced is immaterial and undectable from code. Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @EJP yes, thanks. I'm getting understand. Can you give some clarification how do I do that? I've edited my question, take a look at the beginning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not calling `interrupt()` method to interrupt the thread. Try the following code in `main` method:

```
producer.start();
consumer.start();
producer.interrupt();
consumer.interrupt();
```

Here is one sample output:

`put Thu Oct 01 10:56:10 IST 2015 at 10
List doesn't have the minimun quantity to start a production
I WAS INTERRUPTED
got Thu Oct 01 10:56:10 IST 2015 at 10
got Thu Oct 01 10:56:10 IST 2015 at 9
got Thu Oct 01 10:56:10 IST 2015 at 8
got Thu Oct 01 10:56:10 IST 2015 at 7
got Thu Oct 01 10:56:10 IST 2015 at 6
got Thu Oct 01 10:56:10 IST 2015 at 5
got Thu Oct 01 10:56:10 IST 2015 at 4
got Thu Oct 01 10:56:10 IST 2015 at 3
got Thu Oct 01 10:56:10 IST 2015 at 2
got Thu Oct 01 10:56:10 IST 2015 at 1
got Thu Oct 01 10:56:10 IST 2015 at 0
I WAS INTERRUPTED 2
put Thu Oct 01 10:56:10 IST 2015 at 0`

The points to note (taken from official [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html)) :

1. A thread sends an interrupt by invoking `interrupt` on the `Thread` object for the thread to be interrupted. For the interrupt mechanism to work correctly, the interrupted thread must support its own interruption.
2. The interrupt mechanism is implemented using an internal flag known as the `interrupt status`. Invoking `Thread.interrupt` sets this flag. When a thread checks for an interrupt by invoking the static method `Thread.interrupted`, interrupt status is cleared. The non-static `isInterrupted` method, which is used by one thread to query the interrupt status of another, does not change the interrupt status flag.

Comment: How could I know if some thread was 'woke up', and not restored from time-slice

Comment: @JohnnyWiller You can't. What difference would it possibly make if you could?

Comment: @JohnnyWiller "sleeping" and "waking" happen because of things that your program does.  A thread can only "sleep" by calling some method that _makes_ it sleep (e.g., `Thread.sleep()`, `object.wait()`).  When the method call returns, that means your thread was "woke up".  Time-slicing, on the other hand, is completely invisible to your program.  It's not part of the language, it's not something that any library call does.  It just happens, and there's no way your program can even know when or where it happens.